# Trying to compile opencv_traincascade for OpenCV 3.4.3

Tags: c++, opencv, centos6

When trying to compile the full source it got through the `cmake` and `make` just fine, and it said it built traincascade, but then when doing `make install` it failed.

```
[root@node 3.4.3]$ cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/opencv/3.4.3/ /path/opencv/source/opencv-3.4.3/
...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/opencv/3.4.3

[root@node 3.4.3]$ make -j6
[  0%] Built target gen-pkgconfig
[  1%] Built target libpng
...
[ 93%] Built target opencv_perf_calib3d
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_traincascade
[ 94%] Built target opencv_interactive-calibration
[ 95%] Built target opencv_videostab
[ 96%] Built target opencv_stitching
[ 97%] Built target opencv_test_videostab
[ 98%] Built target opencv_test_calib3d
[ 99%] Built target opencv_test_stitching
[ 99%] Built target opencv_perf_stitching
[ 99%] Building CXX object apps/traincascade/CMakeFiles/opencv_traincascade.dir/traincascade.cpp.o
[ 99%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_traincascade
[100%] Built target opencv_traincascade
[root@node 3.4.3]$ make install
[  0%] Built target gen-pkgconfig
[  3%] Built target libjpeg-turbo
[  6%] Built target libtiff
...
[ 97%] Built target opencv_test_videostab
[ 98%] Built target opencv_traincascade
[ 98%] Built target opencv_createsamples
[ 99%] Built target opencv_annotation
[ 99%] Built target opencv_visualisation
[100%] Built target opencv_interactive-calibration
[100%] Built target opencv_version
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Up-to-date: /path/opencv/3.4.3/share/OpenCV/licenses/ippicv-readme.htm
...
-- Up-to-date: /path/opencv/3.4.3/share/OpenCV/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_silverware.xml
CMake Error at apps/traincascade/cmake_install.cmake:42 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "/path/opencv/3.4.3/bin/opencv_traincascade".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  apps/cmake_install.cmake:37 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:123 (include)



make: *** [install] Error 1
```

When I look in bin, it's right, there is no opencv_traincascade. I tried to compile it myself too, but it failed with a whole bunch of undefined references.

```
[root@node 3.4.3]$ g++ -I /path/opencv/3.4.3/include -o opencv_traincascade ../source/opencv-3.4.3/apps/traincascade/traincascade.cpp
/tmp/ccgslHVv.o: In function `main':
traincascade.cpp:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `cv::getNumThreads()'
traincascade.cpp:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `CvCascadeParams::CvCascadeParams()'
traincascade.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `CvCascadeBoostParams::CvCascadeBoostParams()'
traincascade.cpp:(.text+0x3c0): undefined reference to `CvCascadeParams::printDefaults() const'
traincascade.cpp:(.text+0x3cf): undefined reference to `CvCascadeBoostParams::printDefaults() const'
traincascade.cpp:(.text+0x8a5): undefined reference to `CvCascadeParams::scanAttr(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
traincascade.cpp:(.text+0x998): undefined reference to `CvCascadeBoostParams::scanAttr(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
traincascade.cpp:(.text+0xb39): undefined reference to `cv::setNumThreads(int)'
traincascade.cpp:(.text+0xc11): undefined reference to `CvCascadeClassifier::train(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int, int, int, int, CvCascadeParams const&, CvFeatureParams const&, CvCascadeBoostParams const&, bool, double)'
/tmp/ccgslHVv.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
traincascade.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/ccgslHVv.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
traincascade.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x4b): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
/tmp/ccgslHVv.o: In function `CvParams::~CvParams()':
traincascade.cpp:(.text._ZN8CvParamsD2Ev[_ZN8CvParamsD5Ev]+0xd): undefined reference to `vtable for CvParams'
/tmp/ccgslHVv.o: In function `CvCascadeBoostParams::~CvCascadeBoostParams()':
traincascade.cpp:(.text._ZN20CvCascadeBoostParamsD2Ev[_ZN20CvCascadeBoostParamsD5Ev]+0x9): undefined reference to `vtable for CvCascadeBoostParams'
/tmp/ccgslHVv.o: In function `CvCascadeImageReader::CvCascadeImageReader()':
traincascade.cpp:(.text._ZN20CvCascadeImageReaderC2Ev[_ZN20CvCascadeImageReaderC5Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to `CvCascadeImageReader::PosReader::PosReader()'
traincascade.cpp:(.text._ZN20CvCascadeImageReaderC2Ev[_ZN20CvCascadeImageReaderC5Ev]+0x25): undefined reference to `CvCascadeImageReader::NegReader::NegReader()'
traincascade.cpp:(.text._ZN20CvCascadeImageReaderC2Ev[_ZN20CvCascadeImageReaderC5Ev]+0x36): undefined reference to `CvCascadeImageReader::PosReader::~PosReader()'
/tmp/ccgslHVv.o: In function `CvCascadeImageReader::~CvCascadeImageReader()':
traincascade.cpp:(.text._ZN20CvCascadeImageReaderD2Ev[_ZN20CvCascadeImageReaderD5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to `CvCascadeImageReader::PosReader::~PosReader()'
/tmp/ccgslHVv.o: In function `CvCascadeClassifier::CvCascadeClassifier()':
traincascade.cpp:(.text._ZN19CvCascadeClassifierC2Ev[_ZN19CvCascadeClassifierC5Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to `CvCascadeParams::CvCascadeParams()'
/tmp/ccgslHVv.o: In function `cv::Ptr<CvHaarFeatureParams> cv::makePtr<CvHaarFeatureParams>()':
traincascade.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7makePtrI19CvHaarFeatureParamsEENS_3PtrIT_EEv[_ZN2cv7makePtrI19CvHaarFeatureParamsEENS_3PtrIT_EEv]+0x20): undefined reference to `CvHaarFeatureParams::CvHaarFeatureParams()'
/tmp/ccgslHVv.o: In function `cv::Ptr<CvLBPFeatureParams> cv::makePtr<CvLBPFeatureParams>()':
traincascade.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7makePtrI18CvLBPFeatureParamsEENS_3PtrIT_EEv[_ZN2cv7makePtrI18CvLBPFeatureParamsEENS_3PtrIT_EEv]+0x20): undefined reference to `CvLBPFeatureParams::CvLBPFeatureParams()'
/tmp/ccgslHVv.o: In function `cv::Ptr<CvHOGFeatureParams> cv::makePtr<CvHOGFeatureParams>()':
traincascade.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7makePtrI18CvHOGFeatureParamsEENS_3PtrIT_EEv[_ZN2cv7makePtrI18CvHOGFeatureParamsEENS_3PtrIT_EEv]+0x20): undefined reference to `CvHOGFeatureParams::CvHOGFeatureParams()'
/tmp/ccgslHVv.o: In function `CvCascadeParams::~CvCascadeParams()':
traincascade.cpp:(.text._ZN15CvCascadeParamsD2Ev[_ZN15CvCascadeParamsD5Ev]+0xd): undefined reference to `vtable for CvCascadeParams'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using gcc/7.2.0 and cmake/3.4.3. Let me know what other details you need.

[root@node 3.4.3]$ uname -a
Linux node 2.6.32-696.30.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 22 03:28:18 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Same here, but with 3.4.5 version. It compiles fine on mac os and on Ubuntu machines, but failing to compile on Debian ones.

Answer (score 0):

First, install bunch of libs and dependencies required to build opencv:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -y build-essential cmake pkg-config \
                       libjpeg62-turbo-dev libtiff5-dev \
                       libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev \
                       libatlas-base-dev gfortran python2.7-dev python3.5-dev \
                       python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libdc1394-22-dev \
                       wget unzip ant libatlas-base-dev gfortran pylint \
                       libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
```

Then, download and unpack sources:

```
mkdir opencv
cd opencv
wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.4.5.zip && unzip -qq opencv.zip
wget -O opencv_contrib.zip https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/archive/3.4.5.zip && unzip -qq opencv_contrib.zip
```

Create build dir:

```
mkdir build
cd build
```

Generate makefiles. Tweak the opencv flags you need (I've looked only for Java bindings) and path to contrib module if you've extracted it into different place:

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
          -BUILD_opencv_apps=ON \
          -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE:BOOL=ON \
          -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
          -DBUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
          -DBUILD_opencv_python3=OFF \
          -DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
          -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF \
          -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
          -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../out \
          -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib-3.4.5/modules \
          ../opencv-3.4.5
```

Make & make install, as usually:

```
make -j4

make install
```

For me the key part was the install_prefix variable. For some reason it didn't worked when prefix was set to the build directory but worked fine when I've specified another dir (`out` in my case)